# OpenLayers image geo reference

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to georeference an OpenLayers imagelayer by constructing a bounding box from a known position. The user draws a line on an image, and specifies a length in centimeters. I use an arbitrary position on the map, calculate centimeters per pixel of the drawn line and construct a top left corner by moving that point left and up, and a bottom right corner by moving that point right and down. This works flawlessly except that the positions produce different results depending on the longitude of the position. I would expect the image to be the same size across the world but it gets squished differently on different parts of the world.

I'm moving the position by adding cm lengths to the web mercator coordinates. I know about web mercator distortion and the factor calculation of `1/cos(latitude)` for longitude, but that factor produces a value that is way to big to account for the subtle squishing of the image.

I need a factor calculation that makes sure that every pixel on the image stays square.

The code I use to calculate the bounding box is as follows:

```
// Fetching width and height
const img = await this.geoImage.getImage();
const {width, height} = img;

// Get length of the drawn line in centimeters
const length = this.geoImage.getLineLength();
// Get line coordinates
const coordinates = this.geoImage.getReferenceLine().getGeometry().getCoordinates();
const [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]] = coordinates;

// Calculate the distance in pixels of the line on the image
const pixelDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
// Calculate centimeters per pixel
const centimetersPerPixel = (length * 100) / pixelDistance;

// Construct top left position
const tl = this.geoImage.getCenter().clone();
tl.move(-(width / 2 * centimetersPerPixel), -(height / 2 * centimetersPerPixel));

// Construct bottom right position
const br = this.geoImage.getCenter().clone();
br.move((width / 2 * centimetersPerPixel), (height / 2 * centimetersPerPixel));

// Create extent
const extent = [...tl.toMercator(), ...br.toMercator()];
```

And this is the code for moving a position:

```
/**
* Move the position in centimeters
* @param x
* @param y
*/
public move(x: number, y: number): void {
    // Web mercator coordinates
    const metricPoint = this.getCoordinates();

    metricPoint[0] += x;
    metricPoint[1] += y;

    // Set web mercator coordinates
    this.setCoordinates(metricPoint);
}
```

Comment: An image which is rectangular in a local projection is not rectangular in web mercator - you can only approximate to rectangular by scaling if the image covers a small area, otherwise you must handle the distortion as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html

Comment: Have you tested this? http://viglino.github.io/Map-georeferencer/